# Simple_xml_load_string with multi-level nodes not loading a node

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an XML like this, which has some nodes with macros (e.g. {author}) -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog>
        <book id="test">
            <author>{author}</author>
            <title>{title}</title>
            <genre>{genre}</genre>
            <price>{price}</price>
            <publish_date>{publish_date}</publish_date>
            <description>{desciption}</description>
        </book>
    </catalog>
```

Performing `simple_xml_load_string()` on the above does not return the catalog node, even though no error is displayed (using `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)` and iterating through `libxml_get_errors()`). I also validated the xml at http://xmlbeautifier.com/.

Here is the output of `simple_xml_load_string()` of the above -

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [book] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [author] => {author}
            [title] => {title}
            [genre] => {genre}
            [price] => {price}
            [publish_date] => {publish_date}
            [description] => {desciption}
        )

)
```

The catalog node is missing.

Comment: `echo $xml->asXML();` is the way to see the tree. In your case, `<catalog>` - the root - is represented by `$xml`

Comment: Did the provided solution ever work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Each XML document has exactly one single root element. It encloses all the other elements and is therefore the sole parent element to all the other elements. ROOT elements are also called PARENT elements. So it is not missing 1 node this is just how it works. If you want the name of the root element try this:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
echo $xml->getName();
?>
```

Comment: Additionally: SimpleXML objects don't have regular properties, they're all dynamically generated, thus `var_dump()` doesn't always show actual stuff.

Comment: Okay, but I am not sure if that helps in my case. Please check if you could help with this question of mine, a more detailed one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041887/dynamically-removing-some-nodes-of-a-multi-level-xml

Comment: I have to read an XML string and remove some of the nodes dynamically. I was thus looking for converting the XML string into an object/array, then iterating through it, and removing elements conditionally, and then converting it back to an XML string. So, before I do that, I was looking for converting an XML string into an object/array and back to an XML string. But, since the root node disappears, it seems I cannot recreate the original XML string using some ready made functions like xml_to_obj() and obj_to_xml().